# How Do I fix Yammer on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, yammer

Yammer doesn't seem to work on SharePoint site.

I have yammer configured on my SharePoint site.

How do I fix this?

All time is just said to leave a comment and box is blank all the time.

[image]

Comment: check this https://www.degdigital.com/insights/how-to-use-yammer-for-page-comments-inside-sharepoint/

Comment: @M.Qassas thanks for the information but it don't help me.